# Why is "manquer de" correct, not "manquer à"?

Tags: prépositions, verbes

"Un défilé **dont** aucun homme ne devrait **manquer**, d'ailleurs."

Shouldn't the above be written as "Un défilé **auquel** aucun homme ne devrait **manquer**, d'ailleurs."?

Answer (score 2):

The verb “manquer à” means to be missed by someone in an emotional sense, or be aware that something is missing. The verb “manquer de,” seen here, means to miss, or fail to do something, when followed by a verb. So, “a parade that no man should miss, for that matter.”

- Manquer + direct object = to miss being at/on/in something
- Manquer de + noun = to be lacking
- Manquer de + verb = to miss, to fail to do something
- Manquer à = to miss someone in an emotional sense, be aware that something is missing